# How to migrate sqlite-jdbc project to java-11; the unnamed module reads package org.hamcrest from both junit and hamcrest.core

Tags: java, maven, junit, java-9, hamcrest

I can't migrate my maven project from Java 8 to Java 11. How do I need to resolve module dependencies?

I have defined module `module-info.java` and compilation from command line as 
`mvn clean install` works well, but can't run the project in IntelliJ IDEA.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>vk-post-searcher</groupId>
    <artifactId>VKPostSearcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>VKPostSearcher</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>etu.wollen.vk.PostSearcher</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.28.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

module-info.java

```
module etu.wollen.vk {
    requires java.sql;
    requires sqlite.jdbc;
    requires json.simple;
    exports etu.wollen.vk;
}
```

I get a bunch of erros running from IDE:

```
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package org.hamcrest from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package org.hamcrest.internal from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package org.hamcrest.core from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module junit reads package org.hamcrest from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module junit reads package org.hamcrest.internal from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module junit reads package org.hamcrest.core from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module hamcrest.core reads package org.hamcrest from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module hamcrest.core reads package org.hamcrest.internal from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module hamcrest.core reads package org.hamcrest.core from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module json.simple reads package org.hamcrest from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module json.simple reads package org.hamcrest.internal from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module json.simple reads package org.hamcrest.core from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module sqlite.jdbc reads package org.hamcrest from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module sqlite.jdbc reads package org.hamcrest.internal from both junit and hamcrest.core
Error:java: module sqlite.jdbc reads package org.hamcrest.core from both junit and hamcrest.core
C:\Projects\IDEAProjects\VKpostSearcher\src\main\java\module-info.java
Error:(1, 1) java: module etu.wollen.vk reads package org.hamcrest from both junit and hamcrest.core
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this exact problem before, and I believe I fixed it by adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know if this doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: Works like a charm! Could you explain what's it happening behind the scenes?

Comment: It has something to do with a split package between both JUnit and Hamcrest, and updating Hamcrest fixes it somehow. I can't explain it that well because I'm not too familiar with them, but I recommend you look into *split packages* for more information.